# Keep rows only on condition a value exists in a column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

(apologies for the ugly title of this question)

In my example below, I want to keep rows as combination of product,  date, (and  value?)  for which a  rownnum = 2 exists

| product | date | value | rownum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ball | 2021-09-01 | 3.5 | 1 |
| ball | 2021-09-01 | 2.5 | 2 |
| ball | 2021-10-01 | 3.5 | 1 |
| tshirt | 2021-09-01 | 10.0 | 1 |
| tshirt | 2021-09-01 | 10.0 | 2 |
| ball | 2021-11-01 | 3.25 | 1 |
| tshirt | 2021-11-01 | 16.0 | 1 |
| ball | 2021-12-01 | 5.0 | 1 |
| ball | 2021-12-01 | 2.75 | 2 |

So I would like to get the following table:

| product | date | value | rownum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ball | 2021-09-01 | 3.5 | 1 |
| ball | 2021-09-01 | 2.5 | 2 |
| tshirt | 2021-09-01 | 10.0 | 1 |
| tshirt | 2021-09-01 | 10.0 | 2 |
| ball | 2021-12-01 | 5.0 | 1 |
| ball | 2021-12-01 | 2.75 | 2 |

Can someone please get me on track with keywords to google? Or maybe show an example?

Many thanks.

Comment: thank you for replying @Austin .  ball 3 and 4 qualify because because there is no rownum=2 for that combination of production and date.  (maybe I'm  confusing people with the value column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH eligible as (
   SELECT product, date
   FROM [Table]
   GROUP BY product, date
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
)
SELECT t.*
FROM [Table] t
INNER JOIN eligible e on e.product = t.product and e.date = t.date
```